# How to block ip address using iptables

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, iptables

I got this amount of ip that I want to block

```
tcp        0      0 ns1.example.co:http ec2-54-207-46-155.sa-:51927 SYN_RECV    -                   
tcp        0      0 ns1.example.co:http ec2-52-19-105-249.eu-:60495 SYN_RECV    -                   
tcp        0      0 ns1.example.co:http ec2-52-30-171-255.eu-:42988 SYN_RECV    -
```

I realise the ip address start with ec2 and I know they are from amazon ec2 servers. I want to block all the ip that begin with ec2 on my iptables.

How do I proceed

The further I found is to block by ip such as

```
$ iptables -I INPUT -s 1.2.3.4 -j DROP
```

But I wanna block all ip begin with

```
ec2-52 and ec2-54
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, ec2-52-30-171-255.eu isn't an *IP Address*, it's a **hostname**. To get the associated IP address, you should run *netstat* this way (-n option means no hostname resolution):

```
# netstat -n
```

I don't think dropping all traffic from Amazon EC2 service is a good idea unless you have tons of EC2 containers trying to SSYN you. Here is how you can setup a powerful defense against SYN attacks:

### The quick way *(IPTables only)*

IPTables allows you to limit concurrent SYN connections. Take a look here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-limit-linux-syn-attacks.html.

### The best way *(IPTables + Fail2Ban)*

If you really want to block them one for all, you can still do the above method but instead of just dropping them, logging into a file and setting up a *Fail2Ban* filter that will check this file and ban each client trying to send too many SYN for a given time.
You may be interested in this: https://serverfault.com/questions/640873/how-to-ban-syn-flood-attacks-using-fail2ban.